# Higher Order Gateaux Derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $f: X \to Y$. We say that $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $x \in X$ if for every $0\neq e \in X$ there exists a a bounded linear operator $l_{x}\in B(X,Y)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+te)-f(x)-tl_{x}(e)}{t} = 0. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
If $f$ is Gateaux differentiable at $x$, we write
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x+te)\bigg{|}_{t=0} \equiv \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+te)-f(x)}{t} := l_{x}(e) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, I'd like to understant what does it mean to write
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}f(x+te) \tag{3},\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
i.e. what is exactly the $n$-order Gateaux derivative of $f$. Let's take $n=2$ for simplicity. At first I thought $\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}f(x+te)$ was the derivative of the map $l_{x}: X \to Y$ but, if it is the case, then it should be itself since $l_{x}$ is a linear map, so every higher order Gateaux derivative would be equal to $l_{x}$. So, I think I misunderstood it but I'm really confused to proceed. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The Gateaux derivative is the derivative of the function $g: t\mapsto f(x+te)$. E.g. let $f(x,y) = (\sin(x), y^2)$ and $e = (1,2)$. Then $g(t) = f((x,y) + te ) = f((x+t),(y+2t)) = (\sin(x+t), (y+2t)^2)$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Now, if $f: E \to F$, your $g$ would be a function $g: t \mapsto F$ right? The Gâteaux derivative is the derivative of $g$ in what sense? Is it the Fréchet derivative of $g$?

Comment: If a function is Fréchet differentiable, then it is also Gateaux differentiable, but the converse is not true. The Gateux derivative is the derivative taken along all directions, while Fréchet derivative is more general.

Comment: Let's say $g:t\mapsto f(x+te)$ for some fixed $x,e$, then actually $g:[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon] \to F$, so you can define it's derivative without further specifications. Thus the derivate of $f$ along direction $e$ is given by $g'(0)$.

Comment: I think I get it. You define $g'(0)$ as the element of $F$ which satisfies $|\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}-g'(0)| <\epsilon$ for $0<|t|<\delta$. But still, how to define the second order derivative of $f$ following this idea? I mean, we could make sense of this if $g$ were differentiable on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and the second order derivative of $f$ would be the derivative of $g'$, but our $g$ is differentiable only at $0$, not in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, no?

Comment: Yes, it would require some extra assumptions on $f$ in order for $g''$, or $f''$ to exist. $g''(0)$ would be the second derivative of $f$ in the direction $e$ so to speak.